# How do I implement accurate distance measuring to ground on a rover?

Tags: sensor, laser, distance

I need the end effector to always be at a fixed distance from the ground (for example 10cm.) I know little or nothing about sensors and therefore I don't know which one is the best to use (ultrasound, lidar or other) to be able to measure the distance from the end effector to the ground and then adjust the robotic arm.

The sensor could also be placed on the rover and not on the arm.

What solution do you recommend?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you mount it directly linked to the front axle at the correct height?

Comment: While an optical sensor (IRED, LASER/TOF) looks attractive there surely is an issue with dirt build-up. At the same time, the distance looks quite short for ultrasonic (echo cancellation, resolution)

Comment: @Andyaka because I need that the end effector is as close as possible to the ground (in the post i said 10cm because it is more reasonable but actually the closer the better). Given this proximity I need to know if there will be obstacles (such as pebbles) at the point where the end effector will be.

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing you want to have control about is the distance of the robotic arm with the floor, then a simple ultrasonic is enough and definitely at the arm side. Also take in consideration the resolution of the measurement given by the sensor, this depends of how accurate you need this measurement to be.

If in other case you can to also check the position of the arm in an parallel plane to the floor, then a Lidar would be the best, you can check the right position in space X,Y and Z position in respect with the rover. The only issue is that this would make the programming more complex.